# Syscall numbers of an Ubuntu distribution

Tags: 12.04, kernel

For a given Ubuntu machine how can I figure out the system call number and its corresponding system call function name? Also, would these differ across a 32 bit and a 64 bit machine of the same release?

I'm trying this specifically for "Precise".

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd.h` (64-bit Ubuntu). I assume that's what you are looking for.

This file in turn includes other files in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/`, like `unistd_32.h` or `unistd_64.h`, where you will find the actual system call numbers. So to answer your second question - yes, these numbers may differ across 32-bit and 64-bit flavors of a particular Ubuntu version.

**Edit**: Note that the above paths refer to 64-bit Ubuntu. This would be slightly different for a 32-bit Ubuntu. I don't have one here to check, but `/usr/include/asm/unistd.h` may be a good guess. If all fails, run `locate unistd.h`.